# Javascript calculator display 0 when press any of mathematical operators

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning JavaScript and doing my first project by following Frontend Masters tutorial. Calculator is working perfectly fine except a problem. When i press any mathematical operator button (after passing the first number) the screen shows 0.  I want it to show the last pressed number and not 0.

I just want to display the last entered number on screen when someone press any of maths operators like addition, subtraction.

```js
let runningTotal = 0;
let bufferNumber = '0';
let previousOperator;

const display = document.querySelector('.display')


//initializing function to execute when a button is clicked
document
.querySelector(".calc-buttons")        
.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    clickButton(event.target.innerText);
        
});



//This function checks if selected value is number or symbol
function clickButton(value) {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(value))) { 
        handleSymbol(value);
    } else {
        handleNumber(value);
    }

    rerender()
}

//This function handles the display of number
//this is where initia displayed 0 will be handled
function handleNumber(value) {
    if (bufferNumber === '0') {
        bufferNumber = value;
    } else {   
        bufferNumber += value;
    }
    console.log('buffer number is  ', bufferNumber);
}

//This function executes different symbols.
function handleSymbol(value) {
    switch(value) {
        case 'C':
            bufferNumber = "0";
            runningTotal = 0;
            previousOperator =null;
            break;
        
        case '←':
             if (bufferNumber.length === 1) {
                 bufferNumber = "0";
             } else {
                 bufferNumber = bufferNumber.substring(0, bufferNumber.length-1);
             }
             break;
            
        case '=':
          console.log('= operator displaying result')
             if (previousOperator === null) {
                 return; 
             } 
              flushOperation(parseInt(bufferNumber));
              previousOperator = null
              bufferNumber = "" + runningTotal;
              runningTotal = 0; 
              break;
            
        default:
          console.log('default');
            handleMath(value);
            break;

            }
    
}

    


//handles DMAS 
// We need to convert strings to integers before doing maths calculations on it




function handleMath(value) {
  console.log('handle math function')
    
    const intBuffer = parseInt(bufferNumber);
    if (runningTotal === 0) {
      runningTotal = intBuffer;
    } else {
      flushOperation(intBuffer);
    }
  
    previousOperator = value;
    console.log('previous operator is', previousOperator)
  
    bufferNumber = "0";
}
  
function flushOperation(intBuffer){
  console.log('flush operation')
  if (previousOperator === "+"){
    runningTotal += intBuffer;
  } else if (previousOperator === "−"){
    runningTotal -= intBuffer;
  } else if (previousOperator === "×"){
    runningTotal *= intBuffer;
  } else {
    runningTotal /= intBuffer;
  }
}


function rerender() {
  display.innerText = bufferNumber;
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin-left: 30%;
    padding: 0;
}

.calc {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    
}

.display {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px 5px;
}

.calc-button {
    background-color: rgb(206, 203, 203);
    color: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 24.5%;
    border: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.calc-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(252, 249, 249);

}

.calc-button:active {
    background-color: gray;
}

.calc-button:last-child {
    background-color: rgb(209, 158, 62);
}

.calc-button:last-child:hover {
    background-color: rgb(228, 189, 118);
}

.calc-button:last-child:active {
    background-color:white;
}

.double {
    width: 49.7%;
}

.triple {
    width: 74.9%;
}

.calc-rows {
    display: flex;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- container for overall calculator-->
    <div class='calc'>
       
        
       <section class="display">
           0

       </section>

       <section class="calc-buttons">

            <div class="calc-rows">
                <button class="double calc-button">C</button>
                <button class="calc-button">←</button>
                <button class="calc-button">÷</button>
            </div>

            <div class="calc-rows">
                <button class="calc-button">7</button>
                <button class="calc-button">8</button>
                <button class="calc-button">9</button>
                <button class="calc-button">×</button>
            </div>

            <div class="calc-rows">
                <button class="calc-button">4</button>
                <button class="calc-button">5</button>
                <button class="calc-button">6</button>
                <button class="calc-button">−</button>
            </div>

            <div class="calc-rows">
                <button class="calc-button">1</button>
                <button class="calc-button">2</button>
                <button class="calc-button">3</button>
                <button class="calc-button">+</button>
            </div>

            <div class="calc-rows">                
                <button class="calc-button triple">0</button>
                <button class="calc-button">=</button>
            </div>
        
       </section>

    </div>


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `flushOperation` ? can we code for that ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can run and use debugging tools on

Comment: You probably just need to get rid of `bufferNumber = "0";`

Comment: But you'll probably have to make changes to the code for the number buttons so that they know to remove the old number.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by changing a few things.

when clicking on any of the operator buttons the screen was showing `0` because when the operator was clicked `handleSymbol()` was called and then `handleMath()` get called from the `default case`  and the `handleMath()` function assigned the `bufferNumber` value of 0.

Removing `bufferNumber = "0";` in `handleNumber()` creates another problem which is `bufferNumber` is concatenating two numbers into one. for e.g, if we do `5 + 6`, the `bufferNumber` would become `56`

the `bufferNumber` should store only one number which is the number before clicking the operator and there must be another variable to store another number. I have named this var as `newBufferNumber`

in  `handleSymbol()` function I have added these lines to make the calculator keep working if the calculation continues without clicking the `=` button.

```
 const  ifAnySymbolSelected = value == '÷' ||
        value ==  '×'  ||
        value ==  '+' ||
        value ==   '−';

    if(bufferNumber  && newBufferNumber && ifAnySymbolSelected ) {
        console.log(value, bufferNumber, newBufferNumber)
        flushOperation(parseInt(bufferNumber), parseInt(newBufferNumber));
    }
```

`handleNumber()` function contains few changes

Replacing the line

```
 if (bufferNumber === '0') {
        bufferNumber = value;
    }
```

with

```
  if(symbolSelected) {
        newBufferNumber = newBufferNumber + value
    }
```

to store another digit which the number we click, after clicking calculating `operators`.

On the screen, I am displaying both numbers including the operator. you can always control what you want to show on the screen.

these are the major things I changed. I want you to go through all of it and observe.

hope this helps.

Working fiddle:

```js
let runningTotal = 0;
let bufferNumber = '';
let newBufferNumber = '';
let previousOperator;

const display = document.querySelector('.display')

//initializing function to execute when a button is clicked
document
.querySelector(".calc-buttons")
.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    clickButton(event.target.innerText);
});


//This function checks if selected value is number or symbol
function clickButton(value) {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
        handleSymbol(value);
    }
    else  {
        handleNumber(value);
    }
    rerender()
}

//This function handles the display of number
//this is where initia displayed 0 will be handled

let symbolSelected ;

function handleNumber(value) {
    if(symbolSelected) {
        newBufferNumber = newBufferNumber + value
    }
    else {
        bufferNumber += value;
    }
    console.log(bufferNumber,newBufferNumber)
}

//This function executes different symbols.

function handleSymbol(value) {

    // if calculation goes regularly without clicking '=' operator
   const  ifAnySymbolSelected = value == '÷' ||
        value ==  '×'  ||
        value ==  '+' ||
        value ==   '−';

    if(bufferNumber  && newBufferNumber && ifAnySymbolSelected ) {
        console.log(value, bufferNumber, newBufferNumber)
        flushOperation(parseInt(bufferNumber), parseInt(newBufferNumber));
    }

    if (ifAnySymbolSelected) {
        symbolSelected = true;
        newBufferNumber = ''
    }
    else{
        symbolSelected = false;
    }

    switch (value) {
        case 'C':
            bufferNumber = "0";
            runningTotal = 0;
            previousOperator = null;
            previousOperator = null;
            break;
        case '←':
            if (bufferNumber.length === 1) {
                bufferNumber = "0";
            } else {
                bufferNumber = bufferNumber.substring(0, bufferNumber.length - 1);
            }
            break;

        case '=':
            if (previousOperator === null) {
                return;
            }
            flushOperation(parseInt(bufferNumber), parseInt(newBufferNumber));
            previousOperator = null
            bufferNumber = runningTotal;
            break;
        default:  handleMath(value);  break;
    }
}

// handles DMAS
// We need to convert strings to integers before doing maths calculations on it

function handleMath(value) {
    const intBuffer = parseInt(bufferNumber);
    if (runningTotal === 0) {
        runningTotal = intBuffer;
    }
    previousOperator = value;
}

function flushOperation(intBuffer,newBufferNumber){
    console.log('flush operation')
    if (previousOperator === "+"){
        runningTotal = intBuffer + newBufferNumber;
    } else if (previousOperator === "−"){
        runningTotal = intBuffer - newBufferNumber;
    } else if (previousOperator === "×"){
        runningTotal = intBuffer * newBufferNumber;
    } else {
        runningTotal = intBuffer / newBufferNumber;
    }

    bufferNumber = runningTotal;
}


function rerender() {
    const displayText = `${bufferNumber} ${previousOperator ? previousOperator : ''} ${ previousOperator ? newBufferNumber : ''}`
    display.innerText = displayText;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin-left: 30%;
  padding: 0;
}

.calc {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;

}

.display {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 20px 5px;
}

.calc-button {
  background-color: rgb(206, 203, 203);
  color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 24.5%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.calc-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(252, 249, 249);

}

.calc-button:active {
  background-color: gray;
}

.calc-button:last-child {
  background-color: rgb(209, 158, 62);
}

.calc-button:last-child:hover {
  background-color: rgb(228, 189, 118);
}

.calc-button:last-child:active {
  background-color:white;
}

.double {
  width: 49.7%;
}

.triple {
  width: 74.9%;
}

.calc-rows {
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
}

.as-console-wrapper{display: none!important;}
```

```html
  <!-- container for overall calculator-->
  <div class='calc'>
      <section class="display">
      </section>
      <section class="calc-buttons">
          <div class="calc-rows">
              <button class="double calc-button">C</button>
              <button class="calc-button">←</button>
              <button class="calc-button">÷</button>
          </div>
          <div class="calc-rows">
              <button class="calc-button">7</button>
              <button class="calc-button">8</button>
              <button class="calc-button">9</button>
              <button class="calc-button">×</button>
          </div>
          <div class="calc-rows">
              <button class="calc-button">4</button>
              <button class="calc-button">5</button>
              <button class="calc-button">6</button>
              <button class="calc-button">−</button>
          </div>
          <div class="calc-rows">
              <button class="calc-button">1</button>
              <button class="calc-button">2</button>
              <button class="calc-button">3</button>
              <button class="calc-button">+</button>
          </div>
          <div class="calc-rows">
              <button class="calc-button triple">0</button>
              <button class="calc-button">=</button>
          </div>
      </section>
  </div>
```